# Image map onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

I created an image map (old school, I know. It's my best option) and I would like the opacity to change when I hover with the mouse. I don't know how to achieve this with JS, can anyone help me out? My map code is below.

```
<html>

<img src="img" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
<area target="" alt="tools" title="tools" href="https://datascience.nih.gov/tools-and-analytics" coords="91,61,164,160,156,182,41,218,37,204,34,186,35,167,36,149,41,131,49,112,63,89,79,71" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="comm" title="comm" href="https://datascience.nih.gov/community-engagement" coords="95,60,108,52,124,43,142,38,167,34,189,33,211,38,230,44,247,51,260,60,190,159,165,160" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="work" title="work" href="https://datascience.nih.gov/workforce-development" coords="263,62,274,72,286,84,297,100,307,117,316,143,319,167,319,186,317,205,313,219,198,183,191,159" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="eco" title="eco" href="https://datascience.nih.gov/data-ecosystem" coords="312,223,306,237,297,253,288,266,272,284,251,299,234,309,220,314,201,318,180,321,178,198,198,185" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="infra" title="infra" href="https://datascience.nih.gov/data-infrastructure" coords="175,320,161,319,141,315,126,311,110,304,95,295,83,285,73,275,64,265,57,254,50,242,46,231,42,223,157,184,176,198" shape="poly">
</map>

</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

`AREA` elements define a shape and have no content. The only CSS property that I can confirm they respond to is [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) - specifying properties such as `background`, `opacity` or `border` had no effect that I could produce.

You may be able to change the cursor to an image with alpha channel transparency effects to achieve a change in appearance but it would move with the cursor.

A posible workaround may be to place a content element in front of the image with opacity set to zero (or fully clipped), and turn pointer events off for the element so they pass through to the MAP element. Then in JavaScript process AREA `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to reveal parts of the invisible overlay. (Using an SVG overlay with a program controlled clipping region comes to mind, with optional opacity transitions)

AREA element mouse events bubble up to the `MAP` element, so you can add `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners to the MAP for event delegation.

Comment: Is there a way I can work around this? I attempted to do this in SVG in Illustrator and the entire thing is a nightmare. The image doesn't translate from Illustrator to the web correctly and I can't get it to work.

Comment: See the update for a possible idea to  pursue if it needs to be done. Suitability depends on the graphic design and cost.